# What positive value of a satisfies the equation $\int^{a^{e}}_{e} \frac {dx}{x\int^{ax}_{a}\frac {dy}{y}}=1$

Tags: calculus

What positive value of a satisfies the equation

$\int^{a^{e}}_{e} \frac {dx}{x\int^{ax}_{a}\frac {dy}{y}}=1$

I'm not sure how to start this...

with the inner integral
$x\int^{ax}_{a}\frac {dy}{y} = log y + C$

then $\int^{a^{e}}_{e} \frac {dx}{x(log y + C)\vert^{ax}_{a}}=1$

??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You integartion is incorrect.

\begin{align}
\int^{ax}_a\frac{dy}{y} = \ln|y| \ \bigg|^{ax}_a = \ln|ax| - \ln|a| = \ln|x|
\end{align}
Since we integrate $x$ where $x$ is positive we can drop the absolute value and get:
\begin{align}
\int^{a^e}_e \frac{1}{x\ln(x)}dx
\end{align}
Now substitute $u=\ln(x)$ so that $du=\frac{dx}{x}$. 
\begin{align}
\int^{a^e}_e \frac{1}{x\ln(x)}dx = \int^{\ln(a^e)}_1 \frac{1}{u}du=\ln(\ln(a^e))-\ln(1)=\ln(\ln(a^e))=1
\end{align}
So $\ln(a^e)=e$ and so $a=e$.

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle\int_{a}^{ax}\dfrac{1}{y}dy=\int_{1}^{x}\dfrac{1}{y}dy=\log x$, so $1=\displaystyle\int_{e}^{a^{e}}\dfrac{dx}{x\log x}=\log(e\log a)$, so $\log a=1$, $a=e$.

Answer (score 0):

In fact,

$$\int_a^{ax}\frac{dy}y=\log x\implies1=\left.\int\limits_e^{a^e}\frac{dx}{x\log x}=\log\log x\right|_e^{a^e}=\ldots$$